# iOS App, How to set it to one time registration?

Tags: ios, registration

I am Developing an App, that needs Registration, After launch Screen it shows Registration Screen. After Registration it allows to move on home Screen, and then any Task can be performed on the App.

Now I want my App to save the username and password into device, and on Launch, Application automatically registers the user.

if registration Successfully Achieved, then it automatically shows HomeScreen.
So my Question is, How do I achieve this?

I am beginner, Any Suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Down votter please tell the REASON for down vote?

Answer (score 2):

You should not to save password on your device. It's very not adviser to do that.

At the login, your API should return a session token. It is this one you have to save on device in Keychain. On launch, just retrieve the token in Keychain to be sure there is a session and go to HomeScreen, otherwise log out the user.

You can use this Lib https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith

Comment: Keychain is definitely the way to go.  What sort of authentication will depend on how your API works.  Here is an alternative library for working with the Keychain: https://github.com/square/Valet

Comment: Thanks for guidance.

Comment: Can you guide me towards some tutorial, for doing this thing in objective C. I have performed session maintainance in Php, but don't know about Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UserDefaults` or `Keychain`.

> https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: For saving secure information like passwords UserDefaults is a very bad idea. It's insecure. The keychain is a much better idea, as the keychain is encrypted.

Comment: Because I know about NS user defaults.

Comment: `UserDefaults` is the same as `NSUserDefaults`, just that `UserDefaults` is Swift 3.0 syntax.